# How to programatically open the ion-option-buttons on ion-items

Tags: ionic-framework

Inside my Ionic application, Let's say I have an ion-list with some ion-items inside like this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    I love kittens!
    <ion-option-button class="button-positive">Share</ion-option-button>
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive">Edit</ion-option-button>
  </ion-item>

  // Some other items in the list

</ion-list>
```

I want to programmatically (e.g click of a button), open up the option menu on all the items. Same effect as if the user has swiped all the items to the left simultaneously.

I was not able to find any documentation on this. How can I achieve that?

Comment: does this help you?: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicListDelegate/

Comment: Hey @niklas, I did take a look at that document but there is no information in there that says something about _opening_ option buttons. There is  `closeOptionButtons()` but it's quite the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: i thought it might help. however when initialized, the option buttons have the class `class="item-options invisible"` you might want to try to get rid of the `invisible` programatically

Comment: @niklas, nice idea. I'll try that soon and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @niklas, unfortunately removing or adding the `invisible` class didn't generate the desired effect. As a matter of fact, when i removed it, nothing changed: the button stayed hidden.

Comment: this works if you still need a way to do that: http://www.gajotres.net/programmatically-show-ion-list-options-buttons-in-ionic-framework/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late but it's for someone who wants to do that same.

This not an actual solution but a direction to get it done.

You need to find out the call ionic gives on left/right swipe of item and just call that method from your code(off course after adding required dependencies).

Comment: Any example about how to do that?

Comment: hi @SalahAdDin, it's been long time working on and I'm sure ionic might have this documented for devs. Sorry can't help you now.

Comment: I couldn't find any proper documentation about this.